# How do I remedy this attributeerror in terminal while trying to execute a gradio interface?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, gradio, gr

in Mac terminal, gotten similar errors in Jupyter. When I try and run this python app. I keep getting these errors.

> line 3, in 
> import gradio as gr line 6, in 
> demo = gr.Interface(fn=greet, inputs="text", outputs="text") AttributeError: partially initialized module 'gradio' has no attribute
> 'Interface' (most likely due to a circular import)

I haven't used gradio much so any advice would be much appreciated.

```
from gpt_index import (
    SimpleDirectoryReader,
    GPTListIndex,
    GPTSimpleVectorIndex,
    LLMPredictor,
    PromptHelper,
)
from langchain import OpenAI
import gradio as gr
import sys
import os

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "My API Key"


def construct_index(directory_path):
    max_input_size = 4096
    num_outputs = 512
    max_chunk_overlap = 20
    chunk_size_limit = 600

    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(
        max_input_size,
        num_outputs,
        max_chunk_overlap,
        chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit,
    )

    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(
        llm=OpenAI(
            temperature=0.7, model_name="text-davinci-003", max_tokens=num_outputs
        )
    )

    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path).load_data()

    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex(
        documents, llm_predictor=llm_predictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper
    )

    index.save_to_disk("index.json")

    return index


def chatbot(input_text):
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk("index.json")
    response = index.query(input_text, response_mode="compact")
    return response.response


iface = gr.Interface(
    fn=chatbot,
    inputs=gr.inputs.Textbox(lines=7, label="Enter your text"),
    outputs="text",
    title="Chat",
)

index = construct_index("database")
iface.launch(share=True)
```

I tried the code above and was expecting it to launch the gradio interface.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Python file name, if it's `gradio.py` rename it to something else

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).